# CakePHP SQL Where Count IS

Tags: sql, cakephp

In CakePHP I am trying to make it so that I can count how many instances there are (in this case searchterm) that I can only select that term if there are more than 10 instances.

I have tried this:

```
 $results = $this->Search->find('all',
            array('fields' => array('Search.searchterm'),

                'conditions' => array(


                    array('Search.searchterm LIKE' =>  $this->request->query['term'] . '%'),
                    array('count(Search.searchterm)' => '10'),

              ),

                'group' => array('Search.searchterm'),
                'limit' => 15,

    ));
```

So in this example I am trying to select all search terms where there are 10 instances but I can't get it to work.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do a `find('count')` instead:

```
$results = $this->Search->find('count',
    'conditions' => array(
        array('Search.searchterm LIKE' =>  $this->request->query['term'] . '%'),
    ),
));
```

[And read the manual about the finds](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

Comment: Thankyou.The only thing is that this is being used in ajax for autosuggest so it really needs to be in the same query. I want to do more than just count as I want to get records where count is more than 10.

Comment: You need to do a subquery then in any case or, much better, cache the counts in the table. Assuming I understand you correct. Look for "counterCache" in the documentation.